# How to encrypt and decrypt data using Ring and a PSK or Certificate in Rust?

Tags: encryption, rust, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I like to implement a secure signed token with some data for usage across multiple backend services.

Evaluating the possibilities it looks like the Ring-Library is already one of my project dependencies due to a higer level dependency (warp).

So I thought I could use ring for my purpose too, can I?

Unfortunately I was unable to find any up to date example how to use ring to encrypt and decrypt data with a pre shared key (or SSL-Certificate). All examples I found were outdated. And I was unable to use the documentation of ring to figure out the correct approach by myself.

Can anyone provide a very simple example how to use ring in ^0.16 to encrypt and decrypt data with a pre shared key and/or SSL-Certificate (generated by open-ssl for example)?

Or do you rather think I should not use ring, but another library for my purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure password save" ? If you are trying to implement login, then you should not store the passwords, instead you should use a key-derivation function such as argon2 and store its output.

Comment: Good question and suggestion. Actually I have no problems implementing pasword hash functions, hence I found some working examples for that. So my phrasing was quite misleading. Sorry for that. ... my goal is it to implement something like a secure token which can be encrypted by one service and only be read by some other ones, who know the pre shared key, or public key of the certificate for example...